# How do I properly implement onBlur, is there another issue im overlooking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement form validation for a react form I created. I have an `onChange` to set the value to the state for each text field, then also an `onBlur` validation function, which tests the value against regex. However the component doesn't seem to update with a `true` for its error status (and thus doesn't turn red notifying the user that the field contains something incorrect) until I click another component and start typing.

Here is the `validateOnBlur` function:

```
validateOnBlur = field => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { nameRegex, emailRegex } = regex;
    let errors = this.state.errors

    console.log(!nameRegex.test(e.target.value))

    switch (field) {
        case 'name':
            errors.nameError = !nameRegex.test(e.target.value)
            break;
        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the textfield component from Material-UI which has an error prop, when set to true it turns the component red:

```
<TextField
           error={this.state.errors.nameError}
           id="name"
           placeholder="First/Last"
           label="Legal Name"
           value={this.state.name}
           onChange={this.handleTextField("name")}
           onBlur={this.validateOnBlur("name")}
           fullWidth
       />
```

Comment: why you are preventing default ?

Comment: If this is React, how is the state getting updated.  Doing -> `errors.nameError = ` won't do anything, unless your using some sort of proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never updating the new errors in your `state`.  Instead of `errors.nameError = !nameRegex.test(e.target.value)` use `setState` and actually apply that with

```
this.setState({ errors: { ...errors, nameError: !nameRegex.test(e.target.value) } });
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I had a guess it was with something to do with state not updating